# Need help remembering elegant but forgotten proof of a forgotten theorem

Tags: gr.group-theory

I would like to apologize in advance for this question, it's very vague.

I once attended a lecture in Abstract Algebra where the professor proved a surprisingly fundamental theorem in a remarkably elegant way. Unfortunately I can only remember my own bafflement and one detail.

The proof involved the map $\pi:G^G \to G$ given by $\pi(h) = \prod_{g \in G}h(g)$ and the truth of the theorem depended on a property of the product.

I've long since failed the class, that was my one and only lecture, and I have always regretted forgetting that proof, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As a first guess, G is a finite group, and the proof is the existence of an element of order p for p a prime dividing the order of the group.  Gerhard "I Get Three Guesses, Right?" Paseman, 2017.06.01

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Maybe finite *abelian* group, since if $G$ is non-abelian, it seems as if the product $\prod_{g\in G}h(g)$ may depend on the order of the factors.

Comment: There is a proof by Mackay of Cauchy's Theorem which counts the number of ordered $p$-tuples of a (not necessarily Abelian) group $G$ (of order divisible by $p$) with product $1_{G}.$ The number of such $p$-tuples is a multiple of $p,$ and the number of such $p$-tuples with not all components equal is a multiple of $p.$ Since the total number of such $p$-tuples is $|G|^{p-1}$ which is a multiple of $p$, the number of $p$-tuples with product $1$ and all components equal is a multiple of $p$ ( $ >0$ because of the identity).

Comment: @GeoffRobinson.  Mackey's proof of Cauchy's Theorem is the one I taught.  It is the one really tricky step in the proof of the Sylow Theorem.

Comment: @JasonStarr I thought this was actually Cauchy's proof!

Comment: @IgorRivin :No, it was not Cauchy's proof ( neither was it Mackey!- It was someone called Mackay or maybe McKay- but not the one of Moonshine fame)

Comment: Sorry for writing Mackey instead of Mackay.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson Yes, I think thats the one, thanks! Coincidentally, It was  Arne Meurman from the Monster Vertex Algebra who held the lecture. From what I remember he was also very pleased with the proof

Comment: You should really thank Gerhard Paseman- I wouldn't have realised that that was what you were after, given the phrasing the question, if he had not suggested it in his comment. The key is that if (g_1,g_2,....,g_p) is a p-tuple with (g_1g_2...g_p) = 1, then (even when G is nonAbelian) we have  g_pg_1g_2....g_p-1 = 1, so the number of solutions with not all components equal is divisible by p. Also coincidentally, I remember Lepowski giving an algebra seminar in Chicago in the early 80s on the then new work of Frankl Lepowski and Meurman on the Monster Vertex Algebra. But different McKay here!

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thank you for the help!

Comment: It is McKay, but JAMES Mackay, and here is his proof:http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~yuvalf/McKay%20Another%20Proof%20of%20Cauchy's%20Group%20Theorem.pdf

Comment: You're welcome.  If the question is reopened, you can add it as an answer.  In the meantime, you can edit to add below the question and highlight and summarize this commentary.  Gerhard "Is Not Hungry For Rep" Paseman, 2017.06.02.